# Regular Expression WikiTable

Tags: java, regex, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have wikiTable tag and I would I'm struggling using Java regular expression to extract this table to remove it from other text. An example of the table is follow:

```
{| class="wikitable" border="1"
! بيانات الطرق
! عدد أعمدة الأنارة 
! المسفلتة والمنُارة والمشجرة
! المسفلتة فقط 
|-
| طرق قائمة
| 21.347
| 1.653.000 كم
| 33.889.200 كم
|-
| طرق قيد التنفيذ
| 11.614
| 20.000 كم
| 1.265.790 كم
|-
| طرق مقترح تنفيذها
| 498.631
| 106.000 كم
| 161.000 كم
|}
```

I used:

```
replaceAll("\\{\\| class=\"wikitable.*?\\|\\}", "");
```

but it is not working :(

any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because `.` does not match newline?

If the tables you are extracting contains no templates (thus no } character before the table ending), you can try

```
"\\{\\| class=\"wikitable[^\\}]+\\|\\}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex looks fine, you probably forgot to put the proper flags

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

If you want to use replace you should add flags by prepending them to your regex

```
replaceAll("(?s)\\{\\| class=\"wikitable.*?\\|\\}", "");
```

This should add the dotall flag to your regex